# What type of positive displacement pump is used for vacuum liquid extraction?

Tags: pumps, vacuum

I would like to learn what type of [positive displacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pump#Positive_displacement_pumps) (PD) pumps are used to remove liquids from vacuum applications. I have been searching for an example application, but it seems to be a rare case.

So, imagine you have a liquid trap in a large vacuum system. The flow of water accumulation is so high that it warrants an extraction pump to remove the water. The pressure is about 90% vacuum. The goal is to remove the water to dump so it only need be pumped back up to ambient.

Is there a type of PD pump that is better at this application? From what I have found, very few pump manufacterers publish performance for vacuum operation.

Does anybody have an example of a vacuum application where a PD pump is used to extract liquid?

Comment: What is a "PD pump"?

Comment: @nibot : see the first line of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Condensors in steam plant are a common application - about 90% vacuum and you have to extract the condensate at the rate the engine is using steam - something like 9 lbs per hp/hour if you'll excuse the non-SI units common in steam days.

So you may be looking for a [boiler feedwater pump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiler_feedwater_pump) which not only works against the vacuum, but into a high pressure boiler.

[image]

Comment: This is a great lead! I am looking into BFWPs, but good golly there are a lot of different types. It begs the question, what is the smallest boiler operating from a sub-ambient condenser anybody has heard of?

Comment: Smallest I can find offhand, about 400mm long for the complete steam plant ... http://mainsteam.co.uk/condensers.htm There may well be smaller, but scaling laws limit efficiency...

Comment: @Mart : can you double check that figure? I just used http://www.tlv.com/global/TI/calculator/steam-table-pressure.html entering 10kPa (abs) and it returned a saturated steam temperature of +45C.  (oh right, we agree. I misread ~45 as -45 at first). Yes this is correct, steam plant does work down to 45C or less. A marine environment provides a very convenient way of shedding heat at even lower temperatures; steamships exploit this, many power plants are built on coastlines to exploit it. Inland, you will now understand why cooling towers are so large.

Comment: @mart : Apropos of this : it's also why Organic Rankine Cycle plant has a vanishingly small niche : see http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12108/is-it-possible-to-use-ammonia-vapor-in-steam-turbine/12109#12109 for example. You don't want to vent ammonia or ether to atmosphere (!) so you need a condenser. Having a condenser, there is little to be gained from replacing water. Note the linked example of ORC in another answer shows a prototype plant tested about 30 years ago - not widely adopted.

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected and remove my comment.

Comment: @mart actually I think it was a good question, (roughly, does steam plant really work much below 100C) with a fairly important answer.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a gravity trap so that the liquid flows to the bottom of a sump. The sump can then be isolated from the rest of the system with a valve to allow it to drain under gravity a bit like an airlock.